# How to assign mac address on the physical port of switch device?

Tags: linux, ip, ethernet

I have a Linux embedded device with two port Ethernet switch function.
There is only one ethernet interface which is eth0 and the mac address is, for example: **90:59:af:6e:02:43**.

What I want to do is applying LLDP protocol on the device, so I have to assign other 2 mac addresses on **port1** and **port2** which are **90:59:af:6e:02:44** and **90:59:af:6e:02:45** respectively.

To my knowledge it's impossible to add another mac address on the same ethernet interface so I tried to add dummy interface to represent the port1 and port2:

```bash
$ ip link add lan0 type dummy
$ ifconfig lan0 hw ether 90:59:af:6e:02:44
$ ip link add lan1 type dummy
$ ifconfig lan0 hw ether 90:59:af:6e:02:45
```

And create a bridge:

```bash
$ ip link add name br0 type bridge
```

Add ports to the bridge:

```
$ ip link set dev lan0 master br0
$ ip link set dev lan1 master br0
$ ip link set dev eth0 master br0
```

But it seems doesn't meet my requirement. Does anyone know about it?

Comment: `anyone know about it?` - I'd say nobody knows about it, since nobody knows what device you're talking about.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Please note that nobody knows what the unmet requirement is either. LLDP by itself, being a L2 protocol, doesn't require multiple interfaces to utilize, and only eth0 appears to be a physical interface - br0 and dummies are logical. Please [Edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/734639/edit) your question to clarify it, don't answer in comments so the relevant info is readily available to the community members.